# Not able to plot with ggplot in python

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am trying to get started with the ggplot library in python.  I am using V 2.7.6 in Enthought Canopy.  When I try to run the simple script

```
from ggplot import *

print ggplot(mtcars, aes('mpg', 'qsec')) + \
    geom_point(colour='steelblue') + \
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=[10,20,30],  \
                  labels=["horrible", "ok", "awesome"])
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select_dtypes'
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.